# Akka-http create Chunked entity in Java (convert from Scala)

Tags: akka, akka-http

I am trying to convert the following code from Scala to Java:

```
    object ChunkedStaticResponse {
        private def createStaticSource(fileName : String) = 
          FileIO
            .fromPath(Paths get fileName)
            .map(p => ChunkStreamPart.apply(p))


        private def createChunkedSource(fileName : String) =
          Chunked(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, createStaticSource(fileName))

        def staticResponse(page:String) =
        HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.NotFound,
          entity = createChunkedSource(page))
    }
```

But I am having trouble with the implementation of the second method. So far I got this far:

```
class ChunkedStaticResponseJ {

  private Source<HttpEntity.ChunkStreamPart, CompletionStage<IOResult>> 
     createStaticSource(String fileName) {
     return  FileIO
            .fromPath(Paths.get(fileName))
            .map(p -> HttpEntity.ChunkStreamPart.create(p));
  }

  private HttpEntity.Chunked createChunkedSource(String fileName) {
    return HttpEntities.create(ContentTypes.TEXT_HTML_UTF8, 
           createStaticSource(fileName)); // not working
  }

  public HttpResponse staticResponse(String page)  {
    HttpResponse resp =  HttpResponse.create();
    return resp.withStatus(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND).withEntity(createChunkedSource(page));
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to create the chunked source in the second method. 
Can someone suggest an approach? Also, am I generally on the right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just create a `Chunk` out of every `ByteString` element read from your file, you can leverage `Chunked.fromData` (`HttpEntities.createChunked` in the JavaDSL).

Here's how the result would look on the Scala side

```
  object ChunkedStaticResponse {
    private def createChunkedSource(fileName : String) =
      Chunked.fromData(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, FileIO.fromPath(Paths get fileName))

    def staticResponse(page:String) =
      HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.NotFound,
        entity = createChunkedSource(page))
  }
```

and this would be its JavaDSL counterpart

```
class ChunkedStaticResponseJ {
    private HttpEntity.Chunked createChunkedSource(String fileName) {
        return HttpEntities.createChunked(ContentTypes.TEXT_HTML_UTF8, FileIO.fromPath(Paths.get(fileName)));
    }

    public HttpResponse staticResponse(String page)  {
        HttpResponse resp =  HttpResponse.create();
        return resp.withStatus(StatusCodes.NOT_FOUND).withEntity(createChunkedSource(page));
    }
}
```